# I can't create a pthread_cond

Tags: c

I'm tryng to do the Dining philosophers, and in my code, after a thread drop the stick, they also send a broadcast to all thread waiting in the while loop, to move foward, but apparently this is not happening and I don't know way

https://github.com/lucizzz/Philosophers/blob/main/dinning.c

Comment: [Edit] your question to put all code directly in the question; external links aren't permitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a lot of bugs, but the most fundamental one is that you access shared state without holding the mutex that protects that state. For example, the `while` loop in `routine_1` tests the `stick` array without holding the mutex. It even calls `pthread_cond_wait` without holding the mutex.

This is wrong for many reasons, but the most obvious is this -- what if the `while` loop decides to call `pthread_cond_wait`, but then before you call `pthread_cond_wait`, the thread holding the resources releases it. Now, you are calling `pthread_cond_wait` to wait for something that has already happened -- you will be waiting forever.

You *must* hold the mutex both when you decide whether to call `pthread_cond_wait` and when you actually do call `pthread_cond_wait` or your code will wait forever if a thread releases the resource before you were able to wait for it.

Fundamentally, the whole point of condition variables is to provide an atomic "unlock and wait" operation to avoid this race condition. But your code doesn't use the mutexes correctly.

Comment: you mean like this? https://github.com/lucizzz/Philosophers/blob/main/dinning.c

Comment: Nope. Same problem. Look at line 50. Does the mutex protect the `stick` array or not?

Comment: You need to hold the mutex through the entire process of: 1) Checking the shared state and deciding whether or not to wait. 2) Waiting, if necessary. 3) Changing the shared state.